# Why does CloudTable.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync returns only a fraction of max 1k entities?

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

As we have an event sourced system working with projections, we often have to query our event store for a large number of entities to (re)build our state. 
This is done by:

1.Querying entities on `PartitionKey`, `RowKey` and occasionally extra filtering
2.Processing the result segment 
3.Repeating this until `continuationtoken== null`

Run by an Azure Function (V2), Windows.Azure.Storage 9.3.1.

The issue we are running into is the fact that the segments returned by `ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync` vary in size from around 200~ to 700~ entities. I was able to reproduce this with a simple query on only `PartitionKey`, with no additional filtering. See:

[image]

Documentation states `ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync` could return up to 1k of entities. Any ideas as to why we are not hitting that number? It would (expectantly) dramatically increase performance.

Update: Max query time of 5 sec is not reached, getting a segment takes around 200-300ms.

Answer (score 3):

> Documentation states ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync could return up to 1k
>   of entities. Any ideas as to why we are not hitting that number?

Each query against a table is allowed a maximum of 5 seconds to execute. After this 5 seconds elapses, the table service will return as many entities it was able to find based on the query (subjected to a maximum of 1000 entities). It is quite possible that no entities were found in those 5 seconds and in that case it will return zero entities with continuation token.

From this [`link`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/query-entities#remarks):

> A query against the Table service may return a maximum of 1,000
>   entities at one time and may execute for a maximum of five seconds. If
>   the result set contains more than 1,000 entities, if the query did not
>   complete within five seconds, or if the query crosses the partition
>   boundary, the response includes custom headers containing a set of
>   continuation tokens. The continuation tokens may be used to construct
>   a subsequent request for the next page of data. For more information
>   about continuation tokens, see Query Timeout and Pagination.

Comment: Thanks! And good point, could have been the problem. Just timed the exact same query, getting a segment usually takes round 300-400ms.